# About Rot13-Implementation

Tags: c, rot13

I am trying to implement the rot13-algorithm in C.
But since I am not very familiar with that language, I have some problems with my code right here.

Basically, I want to rotate every letter in args[] to 13 positions up.
But this code seems to be pretty sluggish:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char[] rotate(char c[]) {
  char single;
  int i;
  int alen = sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);
  char out[alen];

  for(i=0;i<=alen;i+=1) {
    if(c[i]>='a' && (c[i]+13)<='z'){
      out[i] = c[i]+13;
    }
  }

  return out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("The given args will be rotated\n");
  int i;
  char rotated[sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0])];

  rotated = rotate(argv);

  /* printing rotated[] later on */
  return 0;

}
```

I know there a lot of holes here - could you show me how to fix this?

Comment: You might like to learn using a debugger (like `gdb` if you're on Linux) to step through your code, this help getting enlightend.

Comment: try to compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99` (on linux) first :)

Comment: I'd say it'll be sluggish, as in it'll never finish (or even start). `char[] rotate(char c[]) { /* ... */ }` won't compile because functions can't return arrays. Also you can't assign to an array as a whole (like in `rotated = rotate(argv);`). Maybe you can be more specific about you problem(s).

Comment: `sizeof` does not give you the number of elements in an array.  It gives you the size (in bytes) of an object's type.  When you receive an array as a parameter, you're really just receiving a pointer to an array.  The logical size of the array could be any size; there is no way to tell.  After all, it's all just bytes in memory.  Therefore, all that `sizeof` can tell you is the size of the pointer.  Also, your code that does the actual rotation is not ROT13.  Consider what happens when c[i] is 'n' or "greater."  You may also want to review how argc and argv work.

Comment: What do you mean with rotate?

Comment: After all the `>= 'a'`, `<='z'`, and `char` arithmetic I'll go on record saying *none* of the solutions discussed here are actually *portable*. But since the OP didn't ask for help with a portable solution, i'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks a lot guys, I solved the problem with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rot13(int c){
  if('a' <= c && c <= 'z'){
    return rot13b(c,'a');
  } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
    return rot13b(c, 'A');
  } else {
    return c;
  }
}

int rot13b(int c, int basis){
  c = (((c-basis)+13)%26)+basis;
  return c;
}

int main() {
  printf("The given args will be rotated");
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    c = rot13(c);
    putchar(c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How @Michael said this `char out[alen]` is not accepted by the compiler because you can't declare an array size with a non constant value. Another problem of your code is the for loop `for( i = 0; i < = alen; i+=1 )` the arrays start on 0 so if you do the for until the `lenght's` position you will be out of the array.

About the code:

1. You must use a pointer to the start of the string as argument of the function, because You can't return arrays in C (But you can return pointers ).
2. Your `if( str[i] >= 'a' && (str[i]+13) <='z')` is incorrect because you will convert some letters into symbols take a look.

________[image]
       --------------------------[image: ASCII CODE]!

```
    void rotate( char * str ) 
    {
        int i = 0;

        /* You do this until you find a '\0' */
        for( i = 0; str[ i ] != '\0' ; i++ ){

            /* Use the pointer notation if you passed a pointer. */
            /* If the letter is between a and m you can simply  sum it. */
            if( *( str + i ) >= 'a' && *( str + i ) < 'n')
                *( str + i ) += 13;       

            /* If the letter is between the n and z you have to do the opposite.*/
            else if( *( str + i ) >= 'n' && *( str + i ) <= 'z')
                *( str + i ) -= 13;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Size of arrays in C must be set at compile time, so you can't use non constant expression for array size.

Consider the below implementation:

```
// in place rotate
void rotate(char *str) 
// str must be a zero-terminated string
{
  int i =0;
  // loop until str itself is not NULL and str[i] is not zero 
  for(i=0;str && str[i]; ++i) // ++i is a pre-increment
  {
    if(str[i] >= 'a' && (str[i]+13) <='z')
    {
      str[i] = str[i]+13;       // modifying str in place
    }
  }
}
```

Then your `main()` can look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{  
  printf("The given args will be rotated: %s\n", argv[1]);

  rotate(argv[1]);

  printf("Rotated: %s\n", argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Update** More advanced version of the transform that takes care of case when `str[i] + 13 > 'z'`

```
  for(i=0;str && str[i]; ++i) // ++i is a pre-increment
  {
      // ignore out of range chars
      if (str[i] < 'a' || str[i] > 'z') continue;
      // rotate 
      for (off = 13; off > ('z' - str[i]); ) 
      {
          off-= (1 + 'z' - str[i]);
          str[i] = 'a';
      }
      str[i]+=off;       
  }
```

Comment: as Antoine Mathys points and as pointed in my answer, the transform is not correct. However +1 for the `i=0;str && str[i]; ++i`

Comment: Added solution for proper ROT13 that would also work for ROT(N)

Comment: @MichaelSh Your claim that an array's size must be a compile-time constant is only true for C before C99, which introduced variable-length arrays. Although this recently got demoted to an optional feature in the current C11 standard.

Answer (score 1):

This function can encode/decode to/from rot13 string. It's compatible with VIM's  `g?` rot13 encoder.

```
void rot13 (char *s) {
    if (s == NULL)
        return;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'm') { s[i] += 13; continue; }
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'M') { s[i] += 13; continue; }
        if (s[i] >= 'n' && s[i] <= 'z') { s[i] -= 13; continue; }
        if (s[i] >= 'N' && s[i] <= 'Z') { s[i] -= 13; continue; }
    }
}
```